# Oracle XMLSequence attribute name and value

Tags: xml, oracle

I am using XML-based auditing for our Oracle system. There are triggers in place on each table to create an XML representation of the record being inserted or updated into a single audit table in our database. The capturing of the audit data is working properlyl, however I am having issues extracting the information using Oracle's XML parsing utilities.

Using our Gender table as an example, the audit table has an XML column like the following:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW num="1">
     <GENDER_ID>2</GENDER_ID>
     <GENDER>Male</GENDER>
     <GENDER_CODE>M</GENDER_CODE>
     <LAST_MODIFIED_BY_USER>bob.smith</LAST_MODIFIED_BY_USER>
     <LAST_MODIFIED_BY_DATE>08-JUN-13</LAST_MODIFIED_BY_DATE>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

I would like to be able to parse the XML into one of two formats.

- Each attribute name within the ROW element would be a column and each attribute value would be the value beneath the column, OR
- Each attribute name and value combination would be on it's own row

Using the following script, I can pull out the values of each attribute:

```
select extractValue(n.column_value, '/*') as Value
from (
      select extract(XMLType(at.xml), '//ROWSET/ROW') as data from audit_table at
      where at.audit_id = 1
     ) x, 
TABLE (xmlSequence(extract(x.data,'/ROW/*'))) n
```

This produces, 5 rows with a single 'Value' column:

- 2
- Male
- M
- bob.smith
- 08-JUN-13

The values by themselves are pretty much useless and I can't figure out how to get the attribute name to be associated with the value. Is there a way I could get the attribute name (i.e. GENDER_ID or GENDER_CODE) to be in an associated column?

There are tonnes of examples of parsing XML if you know what the elements of the XML are. In our case, the audit table will be holding XML for Gender (with 5 columns) and XML for the other tables that have a wide range of column names and numbers.

I would imagine that as the column values can be extracted the attribute names surely can be as well, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getrootelement()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_xml.htm#i1009716) function to get the attribute name. An example,

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (n.COLUMN_VALUE, '/*') AS NODE_VALUE,
       n.COLUMN_VALUE.getrootelement () AS NODE_NAME
  FROM (SELECT EXTRACT (
                  XMLType (
                     '<?xml version = ''1.0''?>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW num="1">
     <GENDER_ID>2</GENDER_ID>
     <GENDER>Male</GENDER>
     <GENDER_CODE>M</GENDER_CODE>
     <LAST_MODIFIED_BY_USER>bob.smith</LAST_MODIFIED_BY_USER>
     <LAST_MODIFIED_BY_DATE>08-JUN-13</LAST_MODIFIED_BY_DATE>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>'),
                  '//ROWSET/ROW')
                  AS data
          FROM DUAL) x,
       TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x.data, '/ROW/*'))) n
```

Output:

```
NODE_VALUE    NODE_NAME
-----------------------------------
2             GENDER_ID
Male          GENDER
M             GENDER_CODE
bob.smith     LAST_MODIFIED_BY_USER
08-JUN-13     LAST_MODIFIED_BY_DATE
```